# Android - How to handle orientation of FragmentActivity?

Tags: android, android-fragments, actionbarsherlock, android-viewpager, android-fragmentactivity

I am currently using the Sherlock package and the view indicator package in my application to create a view pager with the titles at the top and then the action bar over that.

For the most part it works OK however I have noticed that invalidateOptionsMenu() stops working after a screen orientation change.

When my app loads it works fine until I rotate the device to landscape mode, from then on the invalidateOptionsMenu() call never invokes the onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) method.

It's a simple OptionsMenu creation as follows:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

            menu.add("About")
            .setIcon(R.drawable.about)
            .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM);

            menu.add("Refresh")
            .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM);
        return true;
    }
```

Which is located in a SherlockFragmentActivity:

```
public class TestFragActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity
```

I have three classes that extend the Fragment class:

```
OverviewFrag overviewFrag;
ForecastFrag forecastFrag;
LiveFrag liveFrag;
```

And I create them within the SherlockFragmentActivity like this:

```
overviewFrag = new OverviewFrag();
forecastFrag = new ForecastFrag();
liveFrag = new LiveFrag();
```

I then have a FragmentAdapter class as follows:

```
class TestFragmentAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {     
    private int mCount = TAB_TITLES.length;

    public TestFragmentAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return overviewFrag;
        case 1:
            return forecastFrag;
        case 2:
            return liveFrag;
        default:
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mCount;
    } 

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return TAB_TITLES[position];
    }
}
```

The FrgamentPagerAdapter, ViewPAger and PageIndicator are set up in the onCreate as follows:

```
mAdapter = new TestFragmentAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
mPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
mPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
mPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);
mIndicator = (TitlePageIndicator)findViewById(R.id.indicator);
mIndicator.setViewPager(mPager);
```

When the device is rotated I save the 3 Classes hat extend Fragment and return them in the onCreate like this:

```
overviewFrag = savedWeatherInstance.getSavedOverviewFrag();
forecastFrag = savedWeatherInstance.getSavedForecastFrag();
liveFrag = savedWeatherInstance.getSavedLiveFrag();
```

This is all I do, when I rotate the device I seen some strange behavior such as the invalidateOptionsMenu() method not working but also some strange behavior when I call methods in my classes that extend Fragment like this:

```
overviewFrag.refreshTask();
```

This seems to run the refreshTask() but Views don't seem to update correctly.

Can anyone help me as I am quite new to Fragments and I'm not sure I've handled their life cycle correctly here?

Comment: Just go on this link and see the example of Fragment, [http://marakana.com/s/post/1250/android_fragments_tutorial](http://marakana.com/s/post/1250/android_fragments_tutorial)